# Trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my system from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  I did

```
% sudo apt update
% sudo apt upgrade
% sudo apt autoremove
% sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It plows along fine for several minutes and then this happens:

```
Installing the upgrade can take several hours. Once the download has 
finished, the process cannot be canceled. 

 Continue [yN]  Details [d]y

Fetching
Err https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1+esm2                                 
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]                                                                                                   
Err https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1+esm2                                     
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]                                                                                                   
Err https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1+esm2                              
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
```

Comment: Strange. Python2 is deprecated, but the upgrader attempts to upgrade it rather than remove it. You probably should have done a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` before starting the upgrade script, but now it may be too late, and you may need to do a fresh install instead.

Comment: I was able to eliminate some of these complaints by uninstalling python2, then sudo apt-get autoremove.  I guess I need to remove each package that causes the upgrade to bomb, one by one.

Comment: If your APT system still works, it may indeed be a succesfull approach. Still, do a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` before running the upgrader - this is expected.

Comment: this is most likely the same problem as mine https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443890/ubuntu-20-04-5-upgrade-to-22-04-1-exit-with-error-message-failed-to-fetch-unauth

Comment: I went ahead and backed up my entire system, then did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in the end.  It's a scorched earth policy, but it works.  No regrats.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to remove the troublesome packages by hand and try to re-do the upgrade.  It took me several iterations of this, and even using 'aptitude' for one package that was hard to uninstall.  Nevertheless, got over the hump, with only a few hours' efforts.  Much easier than a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

For me I think it may have been because I enabled Ubuntu Pro and then disabled it. Enabling it and its esm services seems to have fixed the problem. Run `pro help` to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list` enabled me to `dist-upgrade`.