# ubuntu 20.04.5 upgrade to 22.04.1 exit with error message failed to fetch unauthorized ip

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates, 22.04, .desktop

Lenovo thinkcentre 510s i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz × 4  8g ram

When i try to upgrade my pc everything looks fine until the download is finished but as soon as the install are about to start i get the errors:

```
Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/libopenexr25_2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1_amd64.deb 401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]

Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore-6.q16-6_6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1_amd64.deb 401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
```

There are more similar lines in the error messages,same ip and programs.

I have searched this site for an answer but found no solution to my problem.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed by disabeling the repo https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu

after disabeling this the upgrade completed without any errors.

Comment: i mark this as solved for now until one of you make a better answer.